# How to make video player like native in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to make video player with next option to keep playing video after rotate device.

I created service with `MediaPlayer` and set `SurfaceHolder` of `SurfaceView` after rotate sceen. It works only for Android 4.x. For Android 2.3.X after replace second call `setDisplay` user doesn't see video, but hears sound of video.

Could you give me direction or example how to implement this option at custom player?

PS. Player shows streaming video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found solution. It's so easy. I set configChanges="orientation|screenSize" for activity with custom player. In this case activity won't be recreated after rotate device it's changed on the same instance.

As result, I don't need service for keeping `MediaPlayer` and don't need replace `SurfaceHolder`.

Comment: Was there anything special you needed to do in onConfigurationChanged?  can you post some example code?